# How do i get AD computer's names tenant and description

Tags: powershell

My idea is to make 2 lists, one from the WSUS server and one from AD. Then compare both lists to find computers that are missing on the wsus server.

```bsh
$separator = "."

$GetWSUSComp = Get-wsuscomputer -UpdateServer $wsus
$GetADComp   = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property CN, CanonicalName, Description | Select-Object CN, CanonicalName, Description

$WSUSArr       = @()


for ($i = 0; $i -lt $GetWSUSComp.Count; $i++){

    $WSUSArr += $GetWSUSComp[$i].FullDomainName.split($separator)[0].ToUpper()

}


Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $WSUSArr -DifferenceObject $GetADComp
```

I want to compare the WSUSArr array to the CN property of $getADComp and put the result in 2 diffrent arrays but I am not sure how i should do that

Comment: Why not do a `foreach` on all AD computers and then check if each computer is in the `wsus`computer array?

Comment: What does `Tenant` refer to in AD?

Comment: @AdminOfThings Tenant is the position within the AD (OUs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar to the following. The idea is to create a collection (array) of custom objects that contain all of the properties you wish to output. Custom objects can be manipulated, i.e. you can add additional properties later or change the values of the current properties.

```
$wsus = Get-WSUSServer -Name behesr-clntwsus -PortNumber 8530
$WSUSComps = (Get-WSUSComputer -UpdateServer $wsus).FullDomainName.ToUpper() -replace '\..*'
$ADComps   = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property Description |
    Select Description,Name,@{Name='InWSUS';Expression={$_.Name -in $WSUSComps}}
```

**Explanation:**

For `$WSUSComps`, you can manipulate the returned collection of `Get-WSUSComputer` in a way where a loop is not necessary. You can use the member-access operator `.` to access the property of all elements of the collection. `ToUpper()` can be applied in the same fashion. `-replace` simply removes the first `.` character and any succeeding characters.

The `Get-AD*` commands allow access to properties that are not in the default property set using the `-Property` parameter. If you have added an attribute called `Tenant`, you can just add that like so `-Property Description,Tenant | Select Tenant,Description...`.

The `Select` command uses a calculated property called `InWSUS` that compares each `ADComputer` object's `Name` property (case-insensitively) to the collection of WSUS names. The comparison is done with the `-in` operator and will return `True` if there is a match. `False` will be returned otherwise.

`$ADComps` stores the output of the AD computers plus the calculated property.

This blueprint can be tweaked to your liking.

Comment: I tried doing something new i edited the AD loop with a hash but this doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: Why do you feel you need a hash or multi-dimensional array?

Comment: You are right there is no need. I edited my code and came up with something new